# BigQuery nested nullable timestamps bug?

Tags: google-bigquery

I think I may have found a bug.

I have a nested schema - a nullable field click can contain a nullable timestamp field called clickTime. (schema snippet below)

```
{
"name": "click",
"mode": "nullable",
"type": "record",
"fields": [
    {
      "name": "clickTime",
      "mode": "nullable",
      "type": "timestamp"
    }
]
}
```

When I try to import JSON data that does not contain the click field (and therefore neither the clickTime field) I get a job failure with the message

"- Could not parse '' as a timestamp"

If I change my schema definition so clickTime is an integer then everything works as expected.   I've checked my data and there are no empty clickTime values - if it's there it is always a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug, we've been able to reproduce it locally and are working on a fix.